# Touch calibration error when using Avalonia UI with Raspberry PI 4 (lite) DRM Mode

Tags: touch, embedded-linux, raspberry-pi4, avaloniaui, avalonia

i followed this tutorial :https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/guides/platforms/rpi/running-on-raspbian-lite-via-drm
and
i use this display: https://www.amazon.de/Elegoo-Display-Monitor-Raspberry-Schnittstelle/dp/B01JRUH0CY

a 3,5 inch SPI Display

with a Raspberry Pi 4 and the offizial distro.

First i installed the lite version and followed the tutorial from Avalonia and Elegoo.

Everything works fine except the touch is not calibrated and seem rotated.
This is a sketch of my touch in drm mode
x = where i have to press to get the buttons pressed
y = actual button position

Touch sketch: https://ibb.co/f2KVtYQ

As you see this is is absolute off and looks rotated.

I tried to calibrate the touch via xinput_calibrator which is not working cause i have no xserver installed on the lite version.
So i installed the xserver and the gui and calibrated there my touch and saved the values.
The touch with my Avalonia UI sample works in the gui but its still broken in terminal mode.
As far as i unterstand the xinput_calibration is only for the xserver and not terminal mode.

So what can i do now to use my touchscreen proper with Avalonia UI in drm mode?

Do something in my code?
Can i calibrate the screen for the terminal?
Do i need a USB touch or other touch device with which this will work?

Thanks for every help!